# GZipInputStream .read() insert zeros into buffer

Tags: java, binary, inputstream, gzipinputstream

I am having a strange program with a GzipInputStream zero filling part of the buffer. I have the fortune of knowing what the bytes are supposed to look like in the stream and I can see the buffer is being filled with 8 correct bytes and 12 zeros (shouldn't be zero)

BYTES SHOULD LOOK LIKE THIS---->
0
20
82
22
-91
27
-96
65
66
65
88
32
32
32
32
81
32
0
0
0
100
78

BYTES ACTUALLY LOOK LIKE THIS--->
0
20
82
22
-91
27
-96
65
66
65
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

The first two bytes represent an integer that determine the size of the variable length (in bytes) payload after the first two. So in this example, the first bytes are 0 20 and in BIG_ENDIAN this gives us a subsequent payload size of 20 bytes.

Here is my code for reading

```
gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(url.openStream());        

byte[] payload = new byte[2];
gzipInputStream.read(payload);
for(int i=0;i<payload.length;i++){
    System.out.println(payload[i]);
}
int payloadSize = ((payload[0] & 0xFF) << 8) | ((payload[1]) & 0xFF);
//read the next payloadSize bytes
byte[] messageBytes = new byte[payloadSize];

gzipInputStream.read(messageBytes);
```

So the first two bytes are those in the payload array and the second 20 bytes are those in messageBytes. Can't figure it out

Modified code thanks to NPE

```
            byte[] payloadSizeBytes = new byte[2];
            int payloadSizeBytesRead = 0;
            while(payloadSizeBytesRead < 2){
                int r = gzipInputStream.read(buffer);
                if(r>0){
                    payloadSizeBytes[payloadSizeBytesRead] = buffer[0];
                    payloadSizeBytesRead++;
                }
            }
            int payloadSize = ((payloadSizeBytes[0] & 0xFF) << 8) | ((payloadSizeBytes[1]) & 0xFF);
            //read the next payloadSize bytes
            byte[] messageBytes = new byte[payloadSize];
            int messageBytesRead = 0;
            while(messageBytesRead < payloadSize){
                int r = gzipInputStream.read(buffer);
                if(r>0){
                    messageBytes[messageBytesRead] = buffer[0];
                    messageBytesRead++;
                }
            }
            for(int i=0;i<messageBytes.length;i++){
                System.out.println(messageBytes[i]);
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The contract on [`read(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) is that it reads *some* data, and returns how many bytes have been read. As things stand, you are ignoring the return value. Instead, you should examine the return value of `read()` and keep calling `read()` until you've read `payloadSize` bytes.

An easy way to do this is by using [`read(b, off, len)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) in a loop:

```
int payloadSize = ((payload[0] & 0xFF) << 8) | ((payload[1]) & 0xFF);
byte[] messageBytes = new byte[payloadSize];

int bytesRead = 0;
while (bytesRead < payloadSize) {
   bytesRead += gzipInputStream.read(messageBytes, bytesRead, payloadSize - bytesRead);
}
```

Comment: Ah! I knew I was missing something important. Thank you. I will try that, get back to you, and post my code!

Comment: Ok, thanks !!! It works now, and I wrote some different code to utilize the returned integer for number of bytes read. However, I am only using a buffer of size 1 since the reading is variable length and I don't want to read too much. This seems inefficient to me but short of modifying the buffer to the remaining payload size, I am not sure how to handle this. In any case, I appreciate it!

Comment: @Submerged: Yes - you can use `read(b, off, len)` instead. See the updated answer.

Comment: I missed that function. Fantastic :) Thanks so much for your help! All is well